# BoxedUnit vs. Unit in Scala

Tags: scala

What's the difference between BoxedUnit and Unit in Scala? When are they used as return type of a function? And what's their relationship with REF? Here's an error of type mismatch that I encountered when dealing with Unit.

> error: java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Can't convert from UNIT to REF(class BoxedUnit) in unit hello.scala at source-/Users/shiyu/Scala/FinalDataFlow/src/print/hello.scala,line-347,offset=13999

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Unit` is the type of the unique value `()`, pronounced "unit".

`BoxedUnit` is an *implementation detail* of Scala on the JVM, used to encode `()` when it enters in a generic context, or is otherwise assigned to `Any`. Normally, you shouldn't hear about `BoxedUnit` in the first place, although it does leak to some user-level features. For example `((): Any).getClass().getName() == "scala.runtime.BoxedUnit"`.

That said, the error you get is clearly a compiler crash, as evidenced by the `AssertionError`. It's not a problem in your code. You should probably [report this as a bug](https://issues.scala-lang.org/) if it is not already in the bug database.

Comment: @srjd what if I try to pattern match on an AnyVal that may contain Unit? For example I tried to use `case Right(Unit)` and it did not match. How I am supposed to do this pattern matching?

Comment: I'm using `case Right(anyVal) if ( anyVal == Unit || anyVal.isInstanceOf[BoxedUnit])` and it works but I find it a bit ugly from a client perspective

Comment: `case Right(())`. The unique value of *type* `Unit` is `()`. The *value* `Unit` is actually the companion object of the `Unit` class, which is not the same as `()`.